# how to author a nuget package that copies the content files to the bin folder of the consuming application

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package

how to author a nuget package that copies the content files to the bin folder of the consuming application.

This is to make sure that any content files (xml, txt etc) are copied to the bin folder of the application project referencing the nuget package. the nuget package should be compatible with .net Framework 4.8 and .net 5/6/7/8 projects.

Please share an example of .props\nuspec file.